# SQL query: put values of an attribute as columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table errors(errorId, category, eDate).

I am trying to show as result the number of errors per week and categories. The query result should be something like:

```
Week    Category1    Category2
01      2            5 
02      0            20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I posted wasn't right.  You need to look into [Crosstab](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA102295771033.aspx) Queries in Access.

Answer (score 0):

Access can't do pivots, as far as I know. In SQL Server you could do this with the PIVOT() construct.

Edit: Actually, take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208956.aspx).

Comment: LOL Access did crosstab queries long before SQL Server had pivot